# Layout file that moves a block breaks entire layout

Tags: magento-2.1, navigation, layout-update

I'm running Magento 2.1.7 CE and I need to move the `navigation.sections` block inside of the `header-wrapper`. I found the reference to `navigation.sections` in `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml` so I created a theme and I'm trying to modify the layout to just move that one block.

Here's the XML I setup to move `navigation.sections` inside of `header-wrapper` (saved under `app/design/frontend/ThemeName/default/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="3columns"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="navigation.sections" destination="header-wrapper" before="logo" />
    </body>
</page>
```

This technically works and when I apply this theme the `navigation.sections` block is moved to that container, but only in developer mode. If I change to production mode with this theme enabled, I run into these issues:

- `magento setup:static-content:deploy` fails (I need to clear a lot of directories under `var/` to get it to work)
- Cannot minify or bundle JS or CSS, it just fails
- Layout on the front page is completely wrecked
- Some CSS and JavaScript files 404. From what I've seen it's files like `require.js` that are included in the original `layout.xml` that I'm trying to extend

I tried copying the original `layout.xml` and just adding the `move` tag but no luck. The only way I can get it to work without Magento having a meltdown is by adding the `move` tag to the original file, but that's not what I want.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my `registration.php`:

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/ThemeName/default',
    __DIR__
);
```

Here's my `theme.xml`:

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <!-- Theme's name -->
    <title>Theme Name</title> 
    <!-- Parent theme -->
    <parent>Magento/luma</parent> 
    <media>
        <!-- Theme's preview image -->
        <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image> 
    </media>
 </theme>
```

I found this in `var/logs/exception.log`:

```
"/path/to/magento/pub/static/frontend/ThemeName/default/en_US/mage/requirejs/mixins.js" 
Warning!file_get_contents(/path/to/magento/pub/static/frontend/ThemeName/default/en_US/mage/requirejs/mixins.js): 
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /path/to/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php:149
```

So the compilation step is looking for `requirejs/mixins.js` which is NOT in my theme, I just want those pulled from the Luma theme. Again, what's an actual fix for this?

This is how I have been clearing cache so far:

```
rm -rf var/cache/* var/generation/* var/view_preprocessed/* var/page_cache/* pub/static/* var/di/* \
&& php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: does your magento logs and php-error log give you more information? seems like the static-content is not generated correctly. Have you run the setup:di:compile command after changing to production mode? Do you use a specific locale? you can add the locale to static-content command setup:static-content:deploy xx_XX

Comment: @juhanix I updated my question with my `registration.php` and `theme.xml`. My theme is literally these 3 files (plus `media/preview.jpg`). No locale, I have used `setup:di:compile` at least 10 times along with `setup:static-content:deploy`. I just checked the logs and I'll be updating my question with a CRITICAL error I found in there

Comment: Not to sound obtuse, but you shouldn't be extending the luma. You need to be falling back to blank or other. Luma is just a demo theme.

Comment: @andyjones Thanks; I updated my `theme.xml` to extend `Magento/blank` but I'm seeing the exact same issue

Comment: @charmeleon great. Have you tried a reinstall? Clearing your vendo - composer update - composer install ? Removing preprocessed - cache - pub/static/frontend - pub/static/adminhtml ? Because i can't see your move affecting your build. It sounds like something is wrong in the whole build. Not theme related.

Comment: I did a system update yesterday and I just nuked the `vendor` directory and then did a `composer install`, I'm still seeing the issue; if I don't apply the theme things work just fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59750/discussion-between-andy-jones-and-charmeleon).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Magento bug: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3754

Currently the workaround is to add a file under `theme/web/images`, e.g.: `theme/web/images/dummy.jpg`